# Percorrer Arvore Binaria

Tags: php, algoritmo

Gostaria de fazer uma função em PHP que percorresse toda a arvore binaria, então fiz esse código.

```
function getTree($id, $count, $conn) {
if ((!isset($count)) || ($count = null)) {
    $count = 1;
}


$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT login FROM usuarios WHERE ID = :id");
$query->execute(array("id" => $id));
$rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if (count($rows) > 0) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        echo "-";
    }

    echo $rows[0]["login"]."<br />";
    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM dados WHERE upline = :id");
    $query->execute(array("id" => $id));
    $rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach($rows as $row) {
        $nivel++;
        getTree($row["id"], $count + 1, $conn);
    }

}
```

}

Ele pega todas as pessoas que estão ali, perfeito. Porem eu gostaria que ele buscasse como a imagem mostra, Porem, olhando a imagem abaixo, essa função trás, 
1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 17, 9, 18, 19, e assim sucessivamente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A função buscaria a segunda linha (numeros 2 e 3) e baseados no id 1;
Depois retornaria e percorreria trazendo o Id 4 e 5, relacionados ao 2, e o 6 e 6 relacionados ao 3 e assim sucessivamente.

Comment: A lógica é clara: o número se desdobra em dois, sendo um o dobro desse número e o outro o dobro mais um, e assim por diante. Fod@ é fazer uma função pra isso. :)

Comment: Você precisa fazer uma iteração em ser em pré-ordem (centro, sub árvore esquerda, sub árvore direita)

Comment: Poderia me dar um exemplo disso?